# how to use while loop to repeat task in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I made it very simple to understand. what i'm trying to run a while loop here to keep adding more data. but unfortunately i can't think of a way!

```
while (True):
    id = input("Enter ID: ")
    name = input("Enter Name: ")
    break;

    def start(k):
        # Selenium Driver Code Here
        file_id = id(k)
        file_name = name(k)

print("ID: ", id)
print("Name: ", name)

while (True):
    restart = input("Add More (y/n): ")
    if restart == "yes" or restart == "y":
        print("Restarting")
    elif restart == "no" or restart == "no":
        print("Not Restarting");
```

upon calling the function it restarted again with the previous entered input.. i tried using **driver.quit()** before **start(k)** but no hope! bit confused on basics.

```
while (True):
     restart = input("Do you have another file (y/n): ")
     if restart == "yes" or restart == "y":
         start(k)
     else: restart == "no" or restart == "n"
         break;
```

***my complete code structure***

```
keys = []
while (True):
    id = input("Enter ID: ")
    name = input("Enter Name: ")
    restart = input("\nAdd More (y/n): ")
    if restart == "yes" or restart == "y":
        print("Restarting")
        continue
    elif restart == "no" or restart == "n":
        print("Not Restarting")
        break;
keys = {
     "id": file_id,
     "name": file_name
}
def start(k):
 chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
 chrome_options.add_argument("")
 ....
 ....
 ....
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start(keys)
```

After entering my **id** & **name** it asks for add more and pressing "**yes**" we have to enter another data. but before that, we have to execute our previous input data.. this is what i'm trying to fix.

*right now what it does is actually ignore our first input data and execute only our last entry.*

Comment: Code trials for _...i tried using driver.close() or driver.quit() before start(k)..._

Answer (score 0):

You seem to over complicate your logic. It is as simple as this:

```
while True:
    ID = input("Enter ID: ")
    name = input("Enter name: ")


    print("ID: ", ID)
    print("Name: ", name)   

    restart = input("\nAdd More (y/n): ")
    if restart == "yes" or restart == "y":
        print("Restarting")
        continue
    elif restart == "no" or restart == "n":
        print("Not Restarting")
        break
```

The `continue` statement starts the while loop again and the `break` statement exits it.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention. i've already tested continue statement what it does is actually when i go for another file it never execute my previous input and execute my latest input after pressing "no" so that means i have to somehow continue after executing my first input data.

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Do What You Want By Another Code Try This Way It's Simple And Effective :**

```
#create a list that store the name and list for ID
names = []
ids = []

#create flag that tell me if user won't enter any other data or he want to
#enter more data
flag = True

#while loop take a flag and will be in the loop while flag is true
while(flag):

    #take the name from user and store it
    names.append(input("Enter The Name: "))

    #Take The ID
    ids.append(input("Enter The ID:"))

    #ask user if he want to continue
    ask = input("Do you want to continue : ")
    if(ask.lower() == 'no' or ask.lower() == 'n') :
        flag = False

#at the end of the loop print the data that were stored in name list and id list
print("Names Is " , names)
print("IDs Is " , ids)
```

You Now Stored The Data You Can Do Any Operation That You Want On It

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand what role selenium plays here.